# Error while copying parquet file into Snowflake table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have staged a parquet file in internal snowflake user stage. When I try to use copy into command to load the data into snowflake table i am getting following error

**Error parsing the parquet file: number of row groups exceeds the max limit (32767)**

My parquet file contains roughly 9 million rows with 11 columns. Can any one guide me on how to overcome this issue.

Note : loading smaller parquet file with less rows works perfectly. problem occurs only when data is huge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently a limitation in Snowflake and there is a plan to address it in the near future. For the time being, you will need to split the files with fewer row groups per file.

You can use as example a Python lib to do that, see [Dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/) and a simple example code:

```
# Load the required Library
import dask.dataframe as dd

# Read the source parquet file named "my_file.parquet"
ddf = dd.read_parquet('my_file.parquet')

# Split the source file into 3 files which will be stored in a sub-folder called "my_files"
# The resulting files found in this sub-folder are the files to ingest within Snowflake
ddf.repartition(3).to_parquet('my_files/')
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you also tell me what is maximum number of allowed row groups in snowflake ?

Comment: We use Apache Arrow and the limitation comes from that lib and is fixed starting with version 0.17.1, see [here](https://arrow.apache.org/release/0.17.1.html). We have a plan to upgrade the Arrow lib.